# Tensorflow: How to improve the image preprocessing speed?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am now using the tensorlfow dataset to implement the SSD image preporcessing method. The code of dataset is:

```
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)

is_training = True if mode == 'Train' else False   

if is_training:    
  dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=shuffle_buffer)

# If we are training over multiple epochs before 
#evaluating, repeat the
# dataset for the appropriate number of epochs.
if num_epochs is not None:
    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs)

if is_training and num_gpus and examples_per_epoch:
    total_examples = num_epochs * examples_per_epoch

total_batches = total_examples // batch_size // 
 num_gpus * num_gpus
dataset.take(total_batches * batch_size)

# Parse the raw records into images and labels. Testing 
has shown that setting
# num_parallel_batches > 1 produces no improvement in 
throughput, since
# batch_size is almost always much greater than the 
number of CPU cores.

dataset = dataset.apply(
  tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(
      parse_record_fn,
      batch_size=batch_size,
      num_parallel_batches=1,
      drop_remainder=True))
dataset = 
dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.contrib.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Where "parse_record_fn" includes random crop and color saturation. The "dataset" is conducted under CPU. I set the batch size 32 and image size 640*640*3. Experimental results shows that the GPU utils is about 34% which means it takes too much time on image preprocessing. Is there any method to improve the speed?

Thanks!